# How do I restrict many2many field from modifying the master model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, odoo

I am adding a many2many field on product form which display some of product details that in another model
I need to edit that field in product form without modifying the details model.

This is the code:

```py
class autopart(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

related = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="relate",relation='car', string="", )


class relate(models.Model):
_name = 'relate'
_rec_name = 'code'

code = fields.Char(string="product Code", required=False)
car = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="cars", string="car", required=True, ondelete='restrict', )
model = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="models", string="",domain="[('car','=', car )]" )
start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
rang = fields.One2many(comodel_name="yearrange", inverse_name="product_id", store=True, string="Years")
ignore = fields.Char(string="Ignore", required=False, )
pro = fields.Integer(string="", required=False, )
```

Comment: Can you please add a simple example?

Comment: You have added many2many field so it will just add link between those 2 models, it will not update anything else.

Comment: what!!!!!!!!!!! didn't understand a thing please elaborate more